# Need help trying to figure how to cear my divs and make page scale to 100%

Tags: css, html

can someone look at my css and tell me why I can't get my container div to wrap around my other divs? I have set the height to 100% and would like to get the container div to be 100% of the screen. I tried the clearfix method with no luck as well as a few other methods that I found on SO. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="container ">
        <div class="header">
        </div>
        <div class="mainContent">
        </div>
        <div class="other">
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>



body{
    font-size: 100%;
    width:96%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: gray;
}

.container
{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1.041666666%;
    background-color: white;
}

.header{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

.mainContent{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 1.041666666%;
    width: 62.5%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}


.other{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0 0 1.041666666%;
    width: 36.458333333%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vwYac/

Answer (score 1):

add the following to your css

check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/YJUa2/1/)

```
html,body{
height:100%;
}
.content{
height: 100%; // calc(100% - 2 x padding);
}
```

For using height in %, the parent elements should also have their height set (in this case `html` and `body`).

You can calculate the exact height using css `calc()` for maincontent and other function as follows:

```
height: calc(100% - (70px  + total height for margins and paddings) )
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `float` for inner `div`s, you can add `overflow:hidden` to container to fix container hight

```
.container
{
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 1.041666666%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

John, try this. It's the best solution I've ever found for the children floating, disappearing parent problem.

```
<div class="container ">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="mainContent">
    </div>
    <div class="other">
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"><!--CLEAR--></div>
</div>

.clearfix {
     clear: both;
     display: block;
}
```